# Hive/Flutter error: 'registerAdapter' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm new to using Hive in Flutter.  I have created a Hive model class along with a generated TypeAdapter, but when I call registerAdapter I get an error that states 'Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'registerAdapter' was called on null.

Here is User.dart:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'User.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class User extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String username;

  @HiveField(1)
  double initialWeight;

  @HiveField(2)
  double heightInches;

  @HiveField(3)
  DateTime initialDate;

  User(
      {this.username, this.initialWeight, this.heightInches, this.initialDate});
}
```

User.g.dart:

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'User.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class UserAdapter extends TypeAdapter<User> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1;

  @override
  User read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return User(
      username: fields[0] as String,
      initialWeight: fields[1] as double,
      heightInches: fields[2] as double,
      initialDate: fields[3] as DateTime,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, User obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.username)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.initialWeight)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.heightInches)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.initialDate);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is UserAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

import 'constants.dart';
import 'controllers/navigation_controller.dart';
import 'models/User.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter()
    ..registerAdapter(UserAdapter())
    ..openBox('user');

  runApp(MyApp());
}
...
```

Here are the dev_dependencies:
hive_generator: ^1.1.0
build_runner: ^2.0.4

Any way I can resolve the error?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error to go away.  Not sure if this was it but I used a typeAdapter Id of 33 this time instead because of this paragraph found at https://pub.dev/packages/hive/versions/0.1.1#register-adapter:

When you want Hive to use your TypeAdapter, you have to register it. Two things are needed for that: An instance of your adapter and a typeId. Every type has a unique typeId which is used to find the correct adapter when a value is brought back from disk. The typeIds 0-32 are reserved for primitive and built in types.

Also, the main method now looks like this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(UserAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox('user');

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```